# Sending the form value to the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension developing and I am creating a chrome extension, which retrieves some data based on the form data given by the user. But, I am not getting how to send the form values dynamically to the chromes extension.
Here is the below code I am using.
**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Bookmark Extension Example",
"description": "POST details of the current page to a remote endpoint.",
"version": "0.2",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["event.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <form id="addbookmark">
        <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>
        <p><label for="url">Url</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="url" name="url" size="50" value="" /></p>
        <p><label for="summary">Summary</label><br />
        <textarea id="summary" name="summary" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea></p>
        <p><label for="tags">Json Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="jsonName" name="jsonName" size="50" value="document.title" /></p>
        <p>
            <input id="submitJson" type="submit" value="Send JSON Object / Value" />
            <!-- <span id="status-display"></span> -->
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
'title': document.title,
'url': window.location.href,
'summary': window.location.href
});
```

**event.js**

```
function getPageDetails(callback) { 

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' }); 

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message)  { 

    callback(message); 
}); 
};
```

**popup.js**

```
function onPageDetailsReceived(pageDetails)  { 
document.getElementById('title').value = pageDetails.title; 
document.getElementById('url').value = pageDetails.url; 
document.getElementById('summary').value = pageDetails.summary;
} 



window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {

chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(eventPage) {

  eventPage.getPageDetails(onPageDetailsReceived);

});
});
```

can any one suggest me how to send the **textbox** **jsonName** value dynamically inorder to get the dynamic data of document as an alert.
for Example, if a user enters, **window.location.href** in the **jsonName**, it should return the value of the entered field as an alert.

Answer (score 0):

One small issue before we start, make sure to include the popup JS in your HTML, like so:

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <form id="addbookmark">
        <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>
        <p><label for="url">Url</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="url" name="url" size="50" value="" /></p>
        <p><label for="summary">Summary</label><br />
        <textarea id="summary" name="summary" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea></p>
        <p><label for="tags">Json Name</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="jsonName" name="jsonName" size="50" value="document.title" /></p>
        <p>
            <input id="submitJson" type="submit" value="Send JSON Object / Value" />
            <!-- <span id="status-display"></span> -->
        </p>
    </form>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

Next, since `content.js` executes on the page when your browser action opens, you can include additional code to open a [`Port`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port) back to the popup through which the page and the popup can communicate. [`connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect) and [`onConnect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onConnect) are the relevant methods here. Like this:

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  'title': document.title,
  'url': window.location.href,
  'summary': window.location.href
});

// Create port.
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({
  name: "page"
});

// Listen for messages.
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  if (message.name === "query") {
    var objectPath = message.query;
    var parts = objectPath.split('.');
    var obj = window;
    var error = false;
    // Get value.
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
      var part = parts[i];
      // Check if in current object or prototype chain.
      if (part in obj) {
        obj = obj[part];
      } else {
        error = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (error) {
      port.postMessage({
        name: "query_error",
        query: objectPath,
        reason: "window." + parts.slice(0, i + 1).join('.')
      });
    } else {
      port.postMessage({
        name: "query_response",
        query: objectPath,
        value: obj
      });
    }
  }
});
```

that takes care of creating the port and listening for queries from the popup. Next:

**popup.js**

```
function onPageDetailsReceived(pageDetails) {
  document.getElementById('title').value = pageDetails.title;
  document.getElementById('url').value = pageDetails.url;
  document.getElementById('summary').value = pageDetails.summary;
}

// Listen for page to connect.
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  if (port.name === "page") {
    console.log("Received page port");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
      if (message.name === "query_error") {
        alert("Error retrieving " + message.query + "!\n" + message.reason + " was not found.");
      } else if (message.name === "query_response") {
        alert("Retrieved value for " + message.query + ": " + message.value);
      }
    });
    // Set button listener.
    document.getElementById("submitJson").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      var value = document.getElementById("jsonName").value;
      if (value !== "") {
        port.postMessage({
          name: "query",
          query: value
        });
      } else {
        alert("You must enter a value!");
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.warn("Received unknown port.");
  }
});

window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(eventPage) {
    eventPage.getPageDetails(onPageDetailsReceived);
  });
});
```

which handles setting up the click listener, sending the query over the port, and handling the response.

There are a few ways to improve the above, like using the port to send the message with the initial page information instead of `sendMessage`, but that should give you an idea of how to proceed. Also make sure to review the existing APIs available in [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). If you can get the information you want (URL, title, etc) that way, it could simplify things!